# Redux can't organize my data base on theirs type

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a problem with my reducer and I need some help please :
In my payload i send `{data,type}`,  and in my reducer I want to check the type to know in which place i will store my payload :

When the retrieve is done , my Reducer look like :

```js
case GRID_GET_ADDITIONNAL_CONFIG_SUCCESS:
            switch (action.payload.type) {
                case 'compo':
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        loading: false,
                        links: {
                            ...state.links,
                            compo: [...state.links.compo, action.payload.data],
                        },
                    };

                case 'traca':
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        loading: false,
                        links: {
                            ...state.links,
                            traca: [...state.links.traca, action.payload.data],
                        },
                    };
                case 'revers':
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        loading: false,
                        links: {
                            ...state.links,
                            revers: [...state.links.revers, action.payload.data],
                        },
                    };
                case 'externaldoc':
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        loading: false,
                        links: {
                            ...state.links,
                            external: [...state.links.external, action.payload.data],
                        },
                    };
                default:
                    return state;
            }
```

My output should be like this :

```js
ReducerName : {
loading : false;
links : {
        compo : { Here an array with all data with 'compo' type},
        traca : { Here an array with all data with 'traca' type},
        revers : { Here an array with all data with 'revers' type},
        externaldoc : { Here an array with all data with 'externaldoc' type},

}
}
```

I think i've missed sommethings in my switch case, does anyone know what is the problem please ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your dispatch function should look somehow like this ...

```
dispatch({
   type: "some type",
   payload : { data } 
});
```

Then in your switch case should be like this:

```
switch (action.type) {
                case 'compo':
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        loading: false,
                        links: {
                            ...state.links,
                            compo: [...state.links.compo, action.payload.data],
                        },
                    };

                case 'traca':
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        loading: false,
                        links: {
                            ...state.links,
                            traca: [...state.links.traca, action.payload.data],
                        },
                    };
                case 'revers':
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        loading: false,
                        links: {
                            ...state.links,
                            revers: [...state.links.revers, action.payload.data],
                        },
                    };
                case 'externaldoc':
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        loading: false,
                        links: {
                            ...state.links,
                            external: [...state.links.external, action.payload.data],
                        },
                    };
                default:
                    return state;
            }
```

This is the common convention which is followed in industry .
I hope you got some key points to understand .
This must resolve your issue , try using this.
Also , try implementing dispatch function in this manner .

Comment: My dispatch is like this : 
dispatch(getElements(projectId,configurationId,'compo'))
the 'compo' is the type, when i want to get traca type I send the same function but with 'traca' instead of 'compo'..